# Backbone.js: Weird .save() error callback

Tags: php, javascript, json, backbone.js

I get an error response from the `.save()` function. The server side php returns me a text and successfully saves the url into database. When I inspect the **response** I can see the text returned by PHP, however I do not understand why it turns in the error callback. What could be the reason?

```
urlToAdd.save({}, {
    success: function () {
        console.log("In here");
    },
    error: function (model, response) {
        console.log(model.toJSON());
        console.log(response);
        console.log("Not in here");
    }
});
```

The server responds with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 19 May 2012 21:31:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Content-Length: 96
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
```

Comment: What does console.log print again? Sorry your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Console print is 'Object
 savetags.html:102
Object
 savetags.html:103
Not in here '. First object is the model and the second one is an object with various attributes which have **responseText** as my php pages return

Comment: what's the http code of the php response? that's how it decides to use success or failure. if it's not a 2xx code, it's a failure

Comment: It its **200** and the *statusCode** is **200**

Comment: Here is the detailed response `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 19 May 2012 21:31:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Content-Length: 96
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
X-Pad: avoid browser bug`

Comment: And you're sure the browser's getting that response too? Only asking because the response looks fine, but if you got it from cURL or something, instead of the browser's developer tools, there might be a difference there. Just guessing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm... Even though the response is valid, the content-type tells the whole story... The expected content-type should be application/json. If your response isn't JSON, error will be invoked every time. If you have a way to encode your response as JSON, you should see the success invoked instead of the error.