# In what way Backbone.js error function is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In Backbone.js in what terms the **error** state is triggered. I'm facing a challange and **error** is triggered even it receives **200**. I've read it an article that success can be forced by sending a **204** status code from php.

What are the circumstances that causes **error** to trigger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone.js: Weird .save() error callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668429/backbone-js-weird-save-error-callback)

Answer (score 0):

If your response is returning anything other than JSON, even with a 200 status, you'll get an error. For instance, in the app I'm building, I'm calling into an old REST endpoint that returns XML. The response is valid, but error gets invoked every time. If you can get your response to return as JSON, the error condition should go away.